# HTML5 Video for non-mobile and Image for mobile

Tags: html

I want to play video if screen is larger than 992px, and image if it is narrower.
Is is possible to do it only in HTML?

My code:

```
<video autoplay="" preload="auto" loop="true" muted="" >
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/gifs/video.mp4" >
    <img src="/images/gifs/image.jpg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can hide the source itself, or if you have to hide the video tag.
Else try moving the img outside of the video tag and use the following in your CSS and add ID's to your video/image:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
#video-id {
display: none; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
#image-id {
display: none; }
}
```